# Rule to redirect page depending the parameter

Tags: .htaccess

What would be the rule to redirect page depending the parameter ?

For example:

I want : `domain.com/en` redirect to `domain.com?lang=en`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ ?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Could you please explain. I want to understand.

Comment: I had written comments in the code. Which part is unclear? Also did you test?